# If g is a primitive root modulo $N$, then g is a primitive root modulo $D$, where $D|N$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

Let *g* be a primitive root modulo $N\ge2$ and $D\ge 2$ a divisor of $N$. Show that the reduction modulo D of g is a primitive root modulo D.

I've tried using Gauss' Theorem, but I'm not quite sure how to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ be the ring of integers modulo $N$, and let $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^{\ast} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ denote the group of units modulo $N$.  The map $x + N\mathbb{Z} \mapsto x + D \mathbb{Z}$ defines a group homomorphism

$$(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^{\ast} \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/D\mathbb{Z})^{\ast}$$

If you can show this homomorphism is *surjective*, you are done.  This is because if $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ is a surjective homomorphism of groups, then generating sets of $G$ are mapped to generating sets of $H$ by $\phi$.

Thus for every integer $x$ which is relatively prime to $D$, you need to find an integer $y$ which is relatively prime to $N$, with the property that $x \equiv y \pmod{D}$.  One way to do this is using the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Thank you! However, I think that would be clearer stated if you noted that (Z/DZ)∗ would be generated by g modulo D. (the image of g, g being a primitive root modulo N). As for your hint concerning the CRT, it feels it should be so, intuitively, but I don't quite seem to manage to formalise it.

Comment: Well, you can't always have answers written exactly how you like them.

Comment: You may write $D = p_1^{f_1} \cdots p_k^{f_k}$, and $N = p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_s^{e_s}$, with $s \geq k$ and $e_i \geq f_i$.  Given $x$, relatively prime to $D$, the Chinese remainder theorem tells you there exists a $y$ such that $$y \equiv x \pmod{p_i^{f_i}}$$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$, and $$y \equiv 1 \pmod{p_i}$$ for $k+1 \leq i \leq s$.

Comment: Does it...? May I ask you clarify that bit?